# Images doesn't appear on iPhone 5 and 4s

Tags: ios, get, uiimageview, uiimage

That's how my tableview looks on the iPhone 5s:

[image]

and that's how it looks on the iPhone 5 and lower:

[image]

Images are being loaded from the server with this method:

```
- (void) downloadImageForCell:(GlobalChatTVCell *)cell indexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    NSString *str = [[_messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"avatar"];

    [Expansion operationWihtRequestString:str сompletion:^(BOOL sucess, NSData *recievedData)
     {
         NSIndexPath *indPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

         if (indexPath != indPath)
         {
             return;
         }

         UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:recievedData];

         if (!img)
         {
             return;
         }

         cell.profileImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:recievedData];
     }];
}
```

Console output for each cell on iPhone 5s looks like this: [image]

On the iPhone 5 and below NSLog doesn't return anything.

Comment: I think you should try once view debugging.